# Most efficient way to filter data with multiple parameters?

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc

So I have something like this right now http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBgVOL

It takes a location, passes it to a GET ajax call which returns me the lat/lng then passes that to my controller. (Yes I know it is messy)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rentals", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String rentResults(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer pageNumber, @RequestParam(value = "lat", required = false) String lat, @RequestParam(value = "lng", required = false) String lng, @RequestParam(value = "rad", required = false) String rad, Map model) {
        int total = 25;

        if (pageNumber == null) {
            pageNumber = 1;
        } else {
            pageNumber = (pageNumber - 1) * total + 1;
        }

        List<ForRent> rentals = new ArrayList();

        int count;
        if (lat == null && lng == null && rad == null) {
            rentals = forRentDao.getRentalsByPage(pageNumber, total);
            count = forRentDao.getNumOfRentals();
        } else {
            count = forRentDao.RentalRadiusCount(lat, lng, rad);
            rentals = forRentDao.RentalRadius(lat, lng, rad, pageNumber, total);

            String latParam = "&lat=" + lat;
            String lngParam = "&lng=" + lng;
            String radParam = "&rad=" + rad;

            model.put("latParam", latParam);
            model.put("lngParam", lngParam);
            model.put("radParam", radParam);
        }

        int page;

        if (count % total == 0) {
            page = (count / total);
        } else {
            page = 1 + (count / total);
        }

        List<Integer> pages = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= page; i++) {
            pages.add(i);
        }

        model.put("pages", pages);

        model.put("rentals", rentals);
        boolean rent = true;
        model.put("rent", rent);

        return "rent";

    }
```

js

```
 function initMap() {

                var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
                        document.getElementById('address'));


                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

                    };


    $('#searchRadius').on('click', function (e) {

        var lati;
        var lng;
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var rad = $('#radius').val();
        var select = document.getElementById('sel');
        var choice = select.value;



        e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=&location=" + address,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            },
            success: function postForm(response) {
                lati = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;
                lng = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;

                if (rad == null) {
                    rad = '10';
                }

                console.log(lati, lng, rad);

                var data = JSON.stringify({
                    lat: lati,
                    lng: lng,
                    rad: rad
                });

                if (choice == 1) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: contextRoot + "/map/radius",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        },
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            window.location = contextRoot + "/rent/rentals?lat=" + data.lat + "&lng=" + data.lng + "&rad=" + data.rad;

                        },
                        error: function (data, status) {
                            alert("bad api call");
                            console.log(status);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status) {
                console.log(data.errors);
            }}
        );
    });
```

so right now It either returns a list of rentals without lat/lng/radius parameters or it will return the list with the applied parameters.

I need to add about 5-10 more parameters to this (for example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGdjoB)

The way I have my controller set up now most likely wont work and will be a huge headache going forward because I'll need alot of if/else statements based on parameters. I am filtering the data using SQL queries at the moment. Would it be better to return all of the data and filter it in memory or is there a better/more efficient way to set this controller response up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your database will be optimized for search and filter; that is its primary use case. Additionally, the database will have access to indices which Java won't have. Moreover, the database is likely to implement a faster search than whatever you try in Java. The database's search implementation may use concurrency, for example.

It's not completely black and white though. Maybe the database is on terribly slow hardware; in that situation: perhaps the Java application server could do the filtering faster. Maybe the database is on a mechanical hard drive, so it's slow at random access (this would make it bad at utilising its index… though Java wouldn't have any index at all).

I'd still recommend pushing the work to the database, since *that's what it's for*.

---

Of course, maybe your search/filter criteria don't fit well into the relational database model. Consider filter criteria with data dependencies — like "find every car for whom an older car exists". This is a bit ham-fisted (and I assume slow) in SQL. The database is only fast at the job it's designed for.

If performance *actually* matters, benchmark it. Try it both ways, and take a measurement.

If performance *doesn't* matter: ask yourself what code is harder to maintain. Constructing SQL queries in a dynamic, parameterized manner can get pretty ugly. But operating on datastructures in Java can get pretty ugly too.

Answer (score 0):

> The way I have my controller set up now most likely wont work and will be a huge headache going forward because I'll need alot of if/else statements based on parameters.

You surely don't. That's how I did a search with five criteria:

```
            .addInUnlessNull("supplier.id", idList)
            .addEqUnlessNull("id", input.templateId)
            .addEqIf(!request.includeDeleted(), "isDeleted", false)
            .addEqUnlessNull("branch.id", input.branchId)
            .addEqUnlessNull("supplier.id", input.supplierId)
```

I'm using Hibernate, but this doesn't matter as this is my own simple interface to it which could be made to plain SQL, too. Just something like

```
MyQuery addEqUnlessNull(String path, @Nullable Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        sql.append(" AND " + path + " = ?");
        args.append(value);
     }
     return this;
}
```

should do. Beware of SQL injection. Parts used in the query should never come from the user. Every insecure input must be used as SQL parameter or at the very least be properly escaped.

But instead of reinventing the wheel, look at [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) or similar. Plain SQL in Java is really outdated. My main point is that for every repetitive operation you need just one line if you write a method.

---

Doing everything in the database is usually the simplest and possibly also the fastest. You can easily speed it up bu adding indexes on important criteria. Note that indexes makes writes slower and that always at most one index per table can be used.

I wouldn't bother optimizing more before you get it running and gets some usage stats. Without them, you can waste your time on rare cases.

In case the whole list isn't too long, you may want to do it differently:
- Filtering in the database.
- Nothing in the application.
- Sorting and paging (i.e., reducing the result to what belongs on a page) in the client.

Optionally, you may do some additional filtering-as-you-type in the client.